# Asking multiple questions with readline nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am attempting to get both username and password from the CLI in a puppeteer project. I get it to ask one question and can use the value just fine, but when I do the second it just freezes on the input. It is almost like it is not actually closing and returning. I cannot seem to figure out what I am missing. I tried to declare the interface in the question method and then destroy it when close is called, but that did not work. I feel like I am close, but I cannot figure out what I am missing.

```
const login = require('../common/login.js');

userId = await login.getUserId();
console.log(userId) //works
password = await login.getPassword();
console.log(password) //does not work
```

login.js

```
const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

var methods = {};

const question = (promptText) => {
    let response;
  readline.setPrompt(promptText)
  readline.prompt();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readline.on('line', (userInput) => {
        console.log('hi');
        response = userInput;
        readline.close();
    });
    readline.on('close', () => {
        console.log('bye');
        resolve(response);
    })

  })
};

methods.getUserId = async() => {
    let username =  question("Username: ");
    return username;
}

methods.getPassword = async() => {
    let password = question("Password: ");
    console.log(password);
    return password;

}

module.exports = methods;
```

Comment: If you are using `async/await` inside `getUserId` then why are using `await` when you are calling the method?

Comment: Good point. I removed the await from inside the function because question was not even async. Still same issue though.

Comment: I got it to work. Not sure if it is right,but it works.  I think the issue was I was closing the readline and it was not being reopened. 
const RL= require("readline")
const question = (prompt) => {
    let response;
    const rl = RL.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
  rl.setPrompt(prompt)
  rl.prompt();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rl.on('line', (input) => {
        response = input;
       rl.close();  
    })
    readline.on('close', () => {
        resolve(response);        
    })
  })
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readline.close()` will close the streams. The below code works for me

```
const rli = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

function input(prompt) {
    return new Promise((callbackFn, errorFn) => {
        rli.question(prompt, (uinput)=> {
            callbackFn(uinput);
        }, ()=> {
            errorFn();
        });
    });
}


const main = async () => {
    amt = await input("Enter the amount to check: ");
    doSomething(amt);
    uname = await input("Enter your name: ");
    doSomethingElse(uname);
    rli.close();
};

main();
```